# Rails: Catch Exception for Invalid SQL Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I allow my user to enter a custom SQL query in an advanced form if he wants, and I feed his input straight into the "where" clause in my search method.

However, of course, sometimes the user will enter an invalid SQL query. Right now, this causes an error page to come up. I want it to instead display an "invalid syntax" statement.

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
        begin 
          includes(:hobbies, :games).where(search)
        rescue SQL_syntax_error_exception # ?
          #display error message
        end
```

I'm puzzled by this because even when I tried the (supposedly) all-inclusive

```
rescue => e
```

it still didn't catch it...

Comment: Oh yeah I'll also need to sanitize it somehow, but I haven't gotten to that part yet. I'm just trying to get the bare functionality first.

Comment: There's a lot of plugins for Rails that make searching way more flexible and avoid the need of stuffing arbitrary user data in your query. What exception is being thrown? Try `rescue Object => e` to get everything, but once you've identified the correct type, rescue *only* that.

Comment: Ok I'l try using a gem lol

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely **not** recommend doing this - you are going to have a tough time  sanitizing the entire where clause with quotes intact.

As for catching the error,

```
begin
  includes(:hobbies, :games).where(search)
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
  # do whatever
end
```

Note that there are bunches of exceptions that might occur here (not just ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) so you might want to do something like:

```
  ...
rescue Exception => e
  if e.class.ancestors.include? ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError
    # rescue stuff
  else
    # re-throw the exception
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just out of curiosity, if my database does not contain any sensitive information (like passwords or user accounts) -- that is, all the information in the database can be legitimately queried through the search box -- is there any need to sanitize the input?

Comment: @ineedahero, IMHO, emphatically yes.  Giving raw access to the database (not sanitizing input) can give access to the file system through "SELECT INTO OUTFILE" or similar depending on DB and configuration, or DROP DATABASE FOO.  It can also allow people to inject Javascript into arbitrary fields which will be executed when displayed on a web page.  Such Javascript can send your session cookies allowing an attacker to hijack the session, or load code from another (evil) source etc.  Probably many other attack vectors, but suffice it to say, always sanitize input.